# Storyboard doesn't show the changes made after update the project from git

Tags: ios, xcode6, uistoryboard

I made a pull request from git to update my project but when I open it in xcode the storyboard doesn't show the changes that were made. When I run the app in my iPhone and the app show the changes. I opened the storyboard file in a text editor and the changes are there. How can I make to show the actual version of the storyboard in xcode? 
I'm using xcode 6.4.

For example this is how the Hearing Test Scene looks in the StoryBoard open in xcode:

[image]

This is how the Hearing Test scene look in the preview or when I run the app in my iPhone:

[image]

The scene doesn't have errors or warnings, so is not a problem of constrains:

[image]

Comment: Interesting bug! If you open the storyboard as XML do you see the differences? It's probably worth clearing derived data and doing a clean build to see if this kicks Xcode into action

Comment: Yeah when i open the storyboard as XML I can see the differences I clean the project but nothing happens I would try clearing the derived data.

Comment: please post the screenshot of story board ViewController in which you expecting changes to be visible with and also size selected

Answer (score 0):

Try change `wAny hAny` at the bottom bar of story board with different size it will visible in one of the different size there. Actually it will show on the same size on which the contents originally added. It heppen a lot with me and I solved that by changing the size

Comment: then try to change the simulated metrics size